# Discard updated value from a valueupdater in a CellTable fails

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I want to check the updated value before persisting it.
If the check fails, I want to discard the update but that doesn´t work.

```
EditTextCell cell = new EditTextCell();
Column<AnObject, String> column = new Column<AnObject, String>(cell) +
{ @Override public String getValue(AnObject object) 
  { logger.info("getVal:"+object.getId()+", "+object.getAttr());
    return object.getAttr();
  }
};

column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<AnObject, String>()
{ @Override public void update(int index, AnObject object, String value)
  { if (checkValue(value)
    { object.setAttr(value);
      databaseUpdate(object);
    } else
    { taskDataProvider.refresh();  // to display the original value. Doesn t work
    }
  }
});
```

The getValue() method of the column is called and returns the old value, but the new edited value is still displayed.
What´s going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call clearViewData method in your else statement like this

`cell.clearViewData(KEY_PROVIDER.getKey(object));
table.redraw();`